# How to replace bubbles with images?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I have a collection of different smiley images that can be used to replace the bubbles in the [bubble chart here](http://jsfiddle.net/VRdjx/1/).

How do I replace that?

As of now, I am appending circles:

```
node.append("circle")
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
.style("fill", "green");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of circle you will have to prepare `<image>` svg element and place it correctly. For this example I used small circle icon:

```
node.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'images/circle.png')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return -d.r/2; })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return -d.r/2; })
    .attr('width', function(d, i) { return d.r + 'px'; })
    .attr('height', function(d, i) { return d.r + 'px'; })
```

**Update:** Solution with different images depends on your design and data structure. One possible solution is to define an array of images:

```
var images = [ 'admiration.png', 'joy.png', 'hope.png', 'sadness.png', 'surprise.png', 'anger.png', 'worry.png', 'frustration.png'];
```

and then select specific image (assumption is that images reside in `images` directory):

```
node.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
        return 'images/' + images[i];
    })
    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return -d.r/2; })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return -d.r/2; })
    .attr('width', function(d, i) { return d.r + 'px'; })
    .attr('height', function(d, i) { return d.r + 'px'; })
```

Comment: This replaces all circles with the same image. I want a different image for each circle. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You need to give different `xlink:href` attributes to the images.

Comment: Thanks for the update. For some reason, this solution is not working for me. The screen is blank and there is no error in the console.

Comment: Such work of art needed further beautification, using mbostock's [latest art work](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9377340). So, here is the [updated and beautiful fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8ux6/).